# Tuning on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS speaker

Tags: sound

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I can no longer use my speaker unless I run an alsamixer command on my terminal to start it up. Is there a way I can fix the problem permanently without necessarily using alsamixer everytime?

Comment: How do you start the speaker in alsamixer?

Comment: Open terminal (CTRL + ALT + T), type alsamixer, ensure below Master and Speaker are (00). If they are (MM), press M to turn them to 00. Thereafter use the top-arrow key to raise their volume levels

Answer (score 0):

You can go through settings, from the sidebar click on sound, there is a bunch of options there that includes testing the speaker too.

Answer (score 0):

I use `pavucontrol` to configure Pulseaudio sound. (You may have to install it.) In the Configuration tab you can choose profiles. In Output Devices tab you can choose which device is the fallback and which port to use. These should affect what is changed by volume control by default.